# Ruby/Rails - Scrapi gem issues grabbing next div text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="tvShow" align="left">
    <div class="clearfix" style="margin:0px 0px;">
        <h3 class="left" style="margin:0px 0px">FIRST TUESDAY BOOK CLUB WITH JENNIFER BYRNE</h3>
    </div>

    <div>Thursday 22nd December at 2.00 pm (60 minutes)</div>

    <div><b>Channel: </b>ABC1</div>
    ...
</div>
```

I'm using the `scrapi` gem to scrape the contents.

This is what I have so far to extract the `h3`:

```
channel_item = Scraper.define do
    process "h3", :name => :text
end

# let scrapi begin

listings = Scraper.define do
    array :programs
    process "div.tvShow", :programs => channel_item
    result :programs
end

# loop through the listings

listings.scrape(uri).each do |program|
    puts program.name.titleize # h3 text
end
```

I'm not entirely sure how to extract the **Thursday 22nd December at 2.00 pm (60 minutes)** and the **Channel: ABC1** text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying ScrAPI when you have already asked a JSON and Nokogiri version of this question?

Comment: You can get to *any* data using Nokogiri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
channel_item = Scraper.define do
  process "h3", :name => :text
  process "div[2]", :time => :text
  process "div[3]", :channel => :text
end
```

http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html#NodeSetExpressions

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the following error: `selector.rb:336:in 'initialize': Invalid selector: [2] (ArgumentError)`
`

Comment: Try `"div[position()=2]"` instead of `"div[2]"`.

Comment: Well, it looks like predicates are not supported in Scrapi's CSS selectors. I'd suggest to swich to Nokogiri instead.

Comment: I ended up using this code with Nokogiri, and it worked just fine. scrAPI, I'm sorry. Is just plain, rubbish. The HTML parser wasn't even working properly.